# ssh command from Windows to Mac: permission denied

Tags: windows, mac, ssh, permissions, ssh-keys

### Objective

I want to access to my local Mac computer (version: High Sierra 10.13.5) from my Windows computer (Windows 10). The purpose is for automation, to remove the password authentication and add SSH keys access. Both machines are on same Wi-Fi.

### Mac Configuration

Here is my sshd_config file:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication no

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# pass locale information
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PxermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Here is my .ssh folder on the Mac:

```
User$ ls -a
.       ..      id_rsa      id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

### Windows Configuration

Here is my .ssh folder on my Windows computer:

```
Répertoire de C:\Users\myName\.ssh

28/06/2018  20:13    <DIR>          .
28/06/2018  20:13    <DIR>          ..
28/06/2018  20:28             1 679 id_rsa
28/06/2018  20:28               397 id_rsa.pub
28/06/2018  21:17             1 608 known_hosts
```

### Keys

I've generated the SSH keys on my Windows & Mac computers to generate the folders, then I copied the public key ".pub" from Windows to the Mac `/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

### Steps Attempted

I ran this in Windows:

```
C:\Users\myName>ssh myName@macbook-air.home -vvv
```

and this was the output:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "macbook-air.home" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to macbook-air.home [2a01:cb00:b4d:7200:1d70:6f19:ec84:50d2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to macbook-air.home:22 as 'myName'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from macbook-air.home
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ZwSw/+863TCoPOsZp7NJIKd79fbX1YR5z7Mc8QeQk+A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from macbook-air.home
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 2a01:cb00:b4d:7200:1d70:6f19:ec84:50d2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'macbook-air.home' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_rsa (000001DFF3B5DC40)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0000000000000000)
debug2: key: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0000000000000000)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:d3nfNGfFM1IIyh2zlebYb4ai5BiDUObJchtnCChDYUY C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: GetFileAttributesExW with last error 2
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: GetFileAttributesExW with last error 2
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: GetFileAttributesExW with last error 2
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myName/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
myName@macbook-air.home: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I'm a bit lost on any steps that I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are accessing the Mac from Windows you need the private key on the Windows system and the public key on the Mac.  The public key is placed into a file called authorized_keys on the host your sshing to (in this case the Mac).  It would be located in:

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This file contains the public keys for clients you will be connecting from.

Make sure you set the permissions on the file using chmod go-rwx authorized_keys.  If its readable by others than the owner I believe ssh will not process the file.

Comment: The question says “I’ve generated the SSH keys on my Windows & Mac computers to generate the folders, then I copied the public key ".pub" from Windows to the Mac”.  So it sounds like you’re suggesting something that the OP has already done.

Comment: The detail provided was unclear about where the key's were placed.  It appeared that two different sets of keys on the two computers were created.  The private key in this case would remain on windows and the public part would be placed on the remote Mac in the file indicated.

Comment: @Hogstrom I create keys on windows and mac to make sure folders will be created, then i copied the public key from (windows) to the id_rsa.pub. But the private key from windows remains on the windows

Comment: What is missing is to copy the public key to the Mac and put it in a file called **authorized_keys**.  This file contains one line for each public key it will process

Comment: Hello, yes it was the missing step. it works now !! Thank you all